# Does IR redo global waitOn subs between routes?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

```
Router.configure
  waitOn: ->
    Meteor.subscribe 'data'
```

Does `data` get torn down and re-subscribed to when I switch from `/bar` to `/foo`, or does it stay subscribed to for the entire session, like the `null` publication?

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment data is discarded and re-subscribed to. You can use `subs-manager` to solve this issue : https://github.com/meteorhacks/subs-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, data is discarded when you change routes.

There are solution out there to solve this. One such solution is provided by @arunoda. Check out this repository: [subs-manager](http://github.com/meteorhacks/subs-manager)

*Usage with Iron Router: just replace Meteor.subscribe() calls with subs.subscribe(), where subs is a new SubsManager().*

```
subs = new SubsManager
Router.configure
    waitOn: ->
       subs.subscribe 'data'
```